# Convert the time stamp UTC to IST using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a suitable way to convert a timestamp from UTC to IST using JavaScript DateTimeStamp "20160108120040".

The timestamp comes from an XML in my body request.

Comment: If you haven't noticed already, javascript is very bad at handling time and dates.  They provide very little in the way of handling timezones and doing conversions.  I usually just AJAX something to a server to be handled when needed.  But you can also try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) I haven't used it but it comes recommended among my friends.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Even moment.js i am not aware of it how to work. will check it and try to implement in my test script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First thing, take a look at [JavaScript date formats](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) and convert your input date accordingly, then you shoud take a look to the [methods available in JavaScript for date manipulation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) (no external library required). It's pretty easy to do something like this:

```
var dateUTC = new Date("yourInputDateInASuitableFormat");
var dateUTC = dateUTC.getTime() 
var dateIST = new Date(dateUTC);
//date shifting for IST timezone (+5 hours and 30 minutes)
dateIST.setHours(dateIST.getHours() + 5); 
dateIST.setMinutes(dateIST.getMinutes() + 30);
```

Comment: Notice that `dateIST` is not "an ist date", it's just a "wrong" date that when calling `.toUTCString()` on will yield a string that's accurate in IST. The date object should only be used for that `toUTCString()` call and not be used elsewhere.

Comment: Helped me alot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

use `toLocaleString` and provide desired timezone:

```js
new Date("yourInputDateInASuitableFormat").toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'})
```

Comment: The above code will give date in mm/dd/yy, hh:mm:ss format. to make it dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm:ss format which is standard for indian time - use this code :-  `new Date("yourInputDateInASuitableFormat").toLocaleString("en-IN", {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'})`

Answer (score 4):

```
const getISTTime = () => {
  let d = new Date()
  return d.getTime() + ( 5.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer

```js
export default class DateIST extends Date {
    constructor(params) {
        super(params)
        console.log(this)
        console.log(this.toString())
        console.log(this.toLocaleString())
        console.log(this.toISOString())
    }

    toISOString() {
        var date = new Date(this)
        date.setHours(date.getHours() + 5)
        date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 30)
        return date.toISOString();
    }
}

var dateIST = DateIST('...')
console.log(dateIST.toISOString())

// For comparision purposes with Date, like when used in Mongoose Schema with ISODate in MongoDB
dbCollectionModel.find({ dateMongoDB: { $lt: dateIST.toISOString() } })
```